# Google Analytics Cyrillic or Unicode naming

Tags: unicode, google-analytics, cyrillic

I try to use Google Analytics for my website and have a problem, that is in Cyrillic naming for the EventCategory (like on the image below). [Here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference?hl=en#eventCategory) is described that for EventCategory the only restriction is Max Length, that is equal to 150 bytes. But I use Cyrillic names with the length at most 17 symbols (that for UTF-8 will be 34 bytes), for example: **Добавиться в друзья**. What is the reason of cutting names and how to prevent it for Cyrillic?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem. In Google Analytics, the parameters in event formed by using [URL encoding](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp). Thus, one Cyrillic symbol encoded by 6 URL symbols. **The solution:** use standard latin alphabet.